# Set background color textivew using parseColor

Tags: android, android-color

I'm trying to set a TextView background color using parseColor, but I'm recieving this error:

Expected a color resource id, but received an RGB color integer.

Can some one help me please?

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, Color.parseColor(product.brand.color)))
```

The object product.brand.color = #123123 (This is an example color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, Color.parseColor(product.brand.color)))
```

with:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(product.brand.color))
```

`ContextCompat.getColor()` returns the color associated with a color resource (e.g., `R.color.primary`). `Color.parseColor()` does not return a color resource ID, which is why you are getting the error. Instead, `Color.parseColor()` returns an actual color, which is what you want for `setBackgroundColor()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
 textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));
```

parse colour from your resources.